# Entitlement Management, Cases, and Accounts

Tags: case, contracts, entitlements

I want to use Entitlement Management to enforce service agreements to my internal and external users, when they make a new case.

When a user creates a case, I want the case to be tied to an Entitlement that has specific Milestones that the Case Assignee has to follow.  For example, if the case created is an API Request, the assignee has to respond within 6 hours as to whether or not this is possible.

Some of the cases created have an Account tied to them, and if so, this account is granted a certain level of service.  Some accounts will be allowed to make 10 cases a month, others will be allowed to make 20.  (Tiered service).

Some cases, however, don't have any account tied to them, and are generic support questions, totally unrelated to any account.  My questions are:

- Why do entitlements need to have an account linked to them?
- Is there  a way to tie entitlements to users or even specific case record types?

I have been pouring through the Entitlement Management documentation and still don't have a firm grasp of how I can use this to accomplish my goals.

Comment: [Cases don't need a parent Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm?search_text=task). In fact, many email2Case and web2Case Cases get created with a null `AccountId`.

Comment: I realized that was actually an error in my question.  I changed it to entitlements.  Why do entitlements need to link to an account?

Answer (score 4):

To create an `Entitlement` record, it has to have an `Account` as relationship is `Master-Detail (Account)`.

`Entitlement` may or may not have `Service Contracts`.

You can take this approach and it has worked for me.

1. Define `Entitlement` process and related milestones. You can define criteria to enter into `milestone`.

For example,

- Milestone for Customer Support case, it is 24 hours.
- Milestones for Billing Support case, it is 36 hours.
- Milestones for Severity 1 issues case, it is 4 hours.

  2. You can define `milestones` based on case recordtypes and other suitable criteria.
  3. Since email-to-case or web-to-case doesn't have any accounts, in that case you can create a `Dummy` account and tag all these kind of cases into it. So that, it will be part of an `Entitlement`.
  4. There could be a possibility that a single case can be handled by different queues or group of users whose SLA's can be different.  So in that scenario, create milestone based on case types or other suitable criteria and specify same type of criteria for case assignments. So, automatically, after a specific case is getting assigned to a queue, automatically milestones will come into effect.

Comment: So you do assign to a dummy account - have you noticed any repercussions to this?  Is it possible to assign milestones based on account criteria?

Comment: You can assign milestones based on Case criterias and do not consider account as criteria for milestones assignment

Comment: or otherwise, whenever case is created you can associate case to the account based on the Contact (via email id)